# How to resolve "Android Package: extra-android-support"？

Tags: android

I have installed the VS2015,and have done some works in Android SDK Manager,as followed bellow

[image: Android SDK Manager info]
but I have found the problem as bellow

[image: VS Error]

Give me some advices,thanks a lot